# Iterating html through tag classes with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm saving some specific tags from webpage to an Excel file so I have this code:

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl

url = "http://www.euro.com.pl/telewizory-led-lcd-plazmowe,strona-1.bhtml"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

tagiterator = soup.h2

row, col = 1, 1
ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText())
tagiterator = tagiterator.find_next()

while tagiterator.find_next():
    if tagiterator.name == 'h2':
        row += 1
        col = 1
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText(strip=True))
    elif tagiterator.name == 'span':
        col += 1
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText(strip=True))
tagiterator = tagiterator.find_next()

wb.save('DG3test.xlsx')`
```

It works, but I want exclude some tags. I want to get only that h2 tags which have 'product-name' class and that span tags which have 'attribute-value' class. I tried to do this by:

```
tagiterator['class'] == 'product-name'

tagiterator.hasClass('product-name')

tagiterator.get
```

And some more which also didn't worked.

Values I want are visible in this poor image I created: https://ibb.co/eWLsoQ
and url is in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did **not** include is writing it to an excel file, **hopefully**, that's something you can do, nevertheless, just write a comment and I'll include the code for this. 
Logic applies, write product information, add row+=1 and column then resets the column...(why do we do this? so the product stays within the same row :). 
*something you've already done*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'}


url = requests.get("http://www.euro.com.pl/telewizory-led-lcd-plazmowe,strona-1.bhtml", headers=header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

find_products = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'product-row'})

for item in find_products:
    title_text = item.find('div',{'class':'product-header'}).h2.a.text.strip() #Finds the title / name of product
    # print(title_text)
    display = item.find('span',{'class':'attribute-value'}).text.strip() #Finds for example the this text 49 cali, Full HD, 1920 x 1080
    # print(display)
    functions_item = item.findAll('span',{'class':'attribute-value'})[1] #We find now the functions or the 'Funkcje'
    list_of_funcs = functions_item.findAll('a') #We find the list of the functions e.g. wifi
    #Now you can store them or do-smt...

    for funcs in list_of_funcs:
        print(funcs.text.strip())
```

Algorithm:

1. We find each product
2. We find tags within each product and extract the relevant information
3. We use the `.text` to extract only the text portion
4. We use for loops to iterate through each product and then iterate through their Functions or the tag that contains the capabilities of product.

Comment: It is very good, but not finding functions like wifi, HDMI, USB etc. for all of the products, only two models of LG.I added funcs in list_of_funcs to list and printed it, for anyone other than these two LG it have "Picture Mastering (or Performace) Index " which is a line above on the site.

Comment: Did you run it it does actually print those...WIFI and such ? Maybe there's a different structure but you can apply the find functions to do the same, give me an url and I'll fix it..

Comment: I did run it on `http://www.euro.com.pl/telewizory-led-lcd-plazmowe,strona-1.bhtml` I see what you are talking about, it just has something to do with the page structure but will fix it later.

Comment: Today I tried some things but it still don't work properly.

Comment: I don't know if I'm going to be able to fix this tonight, however what you need to do is but instead of `functions_item = item.findAll('span',{'class':'attribute-value'})[1]` instead of [1] go through all and put in an IF to search for the div attribute-value  and to find the one that contains the elements USB and such

Comment: I got it with IF statement and len method to ensure that there is more than two parameters in search. Complex way but it works well. Glad you had time to help.