# Iterate through HTML using BeautifulSoup to find tag and string match

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract table data from a website but before I do that I have to find the exact table I'm looking for so am trying to make that work by following the example here ([Iterating html through tag classes with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608008/iterating-html-through-tag-classes-with-beautifulsoup)) and the documentation here (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all).  Yet I can't figure out why the below code doesn't work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString, Tag
import pandas as pd
import re
URL = 'https://aoprals.state.gov/Web920/search_action.asp?PostCode=10323&MenuHide=1&COLABox=1&EducationBox=1&HardshipBox=1&DangerPayBox=1&LQABox=1&PerDiemBox=1&EffectiveDate=20200802'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for header in soup.find_all("h4",text=re.compile('Post \(Cost of Living\) Allowance')):
    nextNode = header
    print(header)
    while True:
        nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling
        
        if nextNode is None:
            break
        if isinstance(nextNode, Tag):
            if nextNode.name == "h4":
                print(nextNode)
                break
```

If I swap in the below it will find the text but I need it to find the tag with the text so I can then later move on to the table the comes after it.

```
for header in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('Post \(Cost of Living\) Allowance')):
```

What am I missing that is preventing it from working like the example and the documentation?

Comment: do you want all table from site or specific one?

Comment: ultimately I want to extract all the tables from the page, combining similar tables into one CSV and separating others that are not similar into their own CSV.  I have a list of all the valid location ids so eventually the code will take in a csv of ids, loop through the dynamic pages of every ID, extract the data, append it to the appropriate data CSV and then write it all out.  I figured I'd try to walk before I run by just proving I could get one table but that is not working out well so far :(

Comment: what I can see from link all tables are different, so you want to save all tables in different csv???

Comment: One way is get all tables for every entry and save it to a separate csv file

Comment: some are similar in that they only have a single rate and thus could be separate columns in the same CSV: post allowance; post differential; danger pay.  The remaining 3 are different and thus would warrant their own CSV.  But the h4 above each table is important because some tables use the same headers (e.g. rate) so knowing how each are introduced helps me label things correctly thus the h4 in the find all.